# nginx as webserver incl. socket.io and node.js / ws:// 400 Bad Request

Tags: node.js, web-services, sockets, nginx, socket.io

i've got this error requests.

[image: Errors from FireBug]

The last sentence in german means "Firefox cant connect to the server which is located in ws://.......".

The server wouldnt be the problem i think.

Because that here is the nginx configuration, because i think there is the problem!

```
server {
    server_name example.org;
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/web;

    location / # for symfony2
    {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp # for symfony2
    {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$)
    {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ ^/socket
    {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
}
```

nginx version: nginx/1.4.7

app.js (thats the server!)

```
var express = require('express'),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
server.listen(8080);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function(request, response)
{
    response.send('OK');
    io.emit('MessageForAll', request.body);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket){});

console.log('Server running on port 8080.');
```

Answer (score 14):

1. Nginx(nginx version: nginx/1.4.6) Change:-

   ```
   server {
           listen   80;
           server_name 255717070.com;
           root /var/www/stack/25571070;
           index  index.html index.htm;

           location / {
           }

           location ^~ /socket {
              rewrite  ^/socket/(.*)  /$1 break; #used to send request to base url
              proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
              proxy_redirect off;
              proxy_pass_request_headers on;
              proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
              proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
              proxy_set_header Host $host;

           }

   }
   ```

**Note:** You need to change `location ~ ^/socket` to `location ^~ /socket`

Node Changes:

1. app.js:

   ```
   app.enable('trust proxy');
   app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
   var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
        debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
   });


   var sockets = require('socket.io')({
     'transports': ['websocket', 'flashsocket','htmlfile','xhr-polling','jsonp-polling']
   });

   var io = sockets.listen(server,{ resource: '/socket.io/','sync disconnect on unload':true });

   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {  
     setInterval(function() {socket.emit('news', { hello: 'hello world' })}, 1000);
   });
   ```
2. index.ejs:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <title><%= title %></title>
       <link rel='stylesheet' href='/socket/stylesheets/style.css' />
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1><%= title %></h1>
       <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
       <div id="divID">

       </div>
       <script src="http://www.25571070.com/socket/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
           <script>
               var socket = io.connect('ws://25571070.com');
               //var socket = io.connect('http://www.25571070.com');
               var i = 0;
               socket.on('news', function(data) {
                   var div = document.getElementById('divID');
                   i = i + 1;
                   div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<p>'+ data.hello+'('+i+')'+'</p>';
                   console.log(data);
               });
           </script>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "25571070",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.6.6",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.2",
    "debug": "~1.0.4",
    "ejs": "~0.8.5",
    "express": "~4.8.6",
    "moment": "^2.8.2",
    "morgan": "^1.2.3",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.0.6",
    "stylus": "0.42.3"
  }
}
```

Firefox Response:

[image: Firefox websocket response]

Chrome Response:

[image: Chrome Websocket Response]

FYI. I have used below version:

- "node": "v0.10.31"
- "ejs": "~0.8.5"
- "express": "~4.8.6",
- "socket.io": "^1.0.6"
- "nginx": "1.4.6"

For Quick Start With node.js go to [node.js-socket.io-express-ngnix-starter](https://github.com/rajeshujade/node.js-socket.io-express-ngnix-starter)

Comment: xhr polling works, i think. Look at the screenshot above. The problem is that ws:// doesnt work. If the system using xhr polling i could use ajax requests to background server instead using a extra server. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @PatrickB I have changed the answer.Tested on Google Chrome Version 37.0.2062.94 (64-bit) and Mozilla Firefox version 32.0.

Comment: Wtf... it doesnt works for me :( I dont know why the server doesnt send 101 switchting protocols...

Comment: @PatrickB Can you please try to setup a new instance on your local server as I said above or put location ^~ /socket on top **just above location/ or below location/** in ngnix configuration.I am sure its happens only because of ngnix configuration. I tried it with your same directory except symfony2 setup. I am updating answer with package.json too. Please check it.

Comment: I did. Thats the result. http://i.imgur.com/F0cfyXs.png Thats the app.js: http://pastebin.com/MVAPLULx

Comment: @PatrickB I am pushing my code and ngnix config in git now. I have tried your code. It working on my system.

Comment: Yes thanks for help. I will checkout your git repository and check it. I could give you access to the server if i cant handle the problem. I think there is something with the nginx proxy... The socket.io/app Server said 400 and thats an error ... also no bad request... an error from the socket.io server. I try to debug nginx and socket.io now.

Comment: I dont understand **socket.io/app**. I think the url should be like this [**http://www.example.com/socket/**]. Also you need to add router in app.js like **var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);**

Answer (score 1):

Can I see the server code?

Have you double-checked that the websocket port is not blocked by any firewall?

I think you've already read [this blog post](http://nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/), right?

Comment: Yes i had. The only port which is accessable from remote hosts is the port 80. The Server port 8080 is local reachable from the nginx server. In your blog post, which i readed before, uses only port 8020 from internet (reachable for everyone) and the port 8010 for internal use. I add the server code for you above. Wait a minute ^^